# how to convert single digit value to date format supported by sqlite3? [ value 0 padding]

Tags: sql, c, database, sqlite

According to the sqlite3 manual, it says the format should be **YYYY-DD-MM.** 
What if i have a variables with 842, 2, 4, and how to convert into the same format?.

I tried with both the functions, **strftime**, and **date**, but it is not padding the value '0', if the digit is single.

Example:

```
'842-2-4'
```

needs to be converted to

```
'0842-02-04'.
```

Comment: The left zeros don't have any value, if you want to keep them then split the number into digits and store the digits in a int array.

Comment: What are the ranges of possible Y/M/D values in the input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int yyyy = 842;
int dd = 2;
int mm = 4;

char buf[11];

sprintf(buf,"%04d-%02d-%02d",yyyy,dd,mm);
```

Comment: I do not see not padding in his question

Comment: @mohammed kallel "I tried with both the functions, strftime, and date, but it is not padding the value '0'"

Comment: the idea is to extract the date values `yyyy` , `dd` and `mm` from time function and then use sprintf to get a string buffer with the format he specified and with value `0` paddinng